# Use fifo file for pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, dump, fifo, pg-dump, pg-restore

With a colleague, we have to transfer a database from an old server to a new machine. So we use pg_dump / pg_restore
The database is large (~ 500GB). We therefore made the choice to use FIFO files to transfer the dump between our servers. The downside is that it takes 4h for the export (pg_dump -Fc), 20min for the transfer and 5h for the import (pg_restore). But we asked ourselves the question: would it be possible to use FIFO files without going through an intermediate dump file so that the pg_dump feeds the pg_restore directly?

I did a test with a small schema with the export: pg_dump (= sql format) and the import: psql. It works. But this is not possible for all the base.

Comment: Have you  looked at replication? Are the servers on the same OS and the Postgres versions the same?

Comment: We need to upgrade our database server (os linux and postgres 9 to postgres 10).
So we have to transfer the data. As I said we were looking for a faster way to create and copy this database from the old to the new server.